# Computing degree of curve morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Consider $X\subseteq \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}\times \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ defined by the equation $(x_0^3+x_1^3)y_0^2+y_1^2(x_0^3-x_1^3)$ and $f:X\to \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ defined by $([a_0:a_1],[b_0:b_1])\mapsto [a_0:a_1]$.

My question si how do we find the degree of this morphism ? Since it's $[K(\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}),K(X)]$ and $X$ is projective, we can replace $X$ by an affine chart, which could be $X\cap (U_0\times U_0)$ where $U_0$ is the cart of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ defined by $\{x_0\neq 0\}$ so the first coordinate is non zero. in this case we would've that $U$ is defined by the equation $1+x_1^3+y_1^2-x_1^3y_1^2$.

So $K(U)=\operatorname{Frac}(A(U))\cong \operatorname{Frac}\mathbb C[x,y]/(1+x^3+y^2-x^3y^2)$ but i can't compute the required dimension.

Is there maybe an other way or I should continue with this ?

Comment: Compute the fiber over a point $[a_0:a_1]$: this is $V((a_0^3+a_1^3)y_0^2+(a_0^3-a_1^3)y_1^2)\subset\Bbb P^1_{[y_0:y_1]}$. Can you determine how many points with multiplicity this is?

Comment: @KReiser So we can suppose $a_0=1$ (and then $a_1=1$), we get $a_1^3(y_0^2-y_1^2)+y_0^2+y_1^2$. Then it depends on $a_1$, I would consider the cases $a_1=0$, $a_1\in\{-1,1\}$ and the rest separately. But why are we doing this ?

Comment: The degree of a morphism of curves is equal to the number of points in a fiber (counted appropriately, i.e. including multiplicity and degree of field extension).

Comment: @KReiser Do you know where this is written in Hartshorne for example ? So here in the case $a_1=0$ I find that there are two points in the fiber, so the degree will be 2 am I right ? And I don't need to consider the case $a_1=1$ instead of $a_0=1$ since I guess that we could take any point, is this correct ?

Comment: A finite map of curves is flat by III.9.7; a finite flat map $f:X\to Y$ has $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ locally free on $Y$ by III.9.2(e). This provides enough to conclude. And yes, no need to consider specific values of $a_i$.